# Which is faster to analyze between .str.contains and "string" in "string"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, contains

I have to create a column in a dataframe with hundreds of conditions. This includes looking into text. :

```
print(df["Short description"].str.contains("e"))
```

This code works on a single line but when I include it in my function with all the others, I get the error :

```
attributeerror 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Now, if I execute a basic elseif but not for a Dataframe in my function with everything else, it works :

```
"e" in df2["Short description"]: return "things"
```

So I would need to know which one is faster for Python, knowing that my function is :

```
df2["Deversement Service"] = df2.swifter.apply(conditions, axis=1)
```

Where is condition is hundreds of else if similar to the one above.

Thanks for your help

Comment: "I would need to know which one is faster for Python" - you can test it: https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/timeit.html

Comment: I thought about it, unfortunately I have too many conditions. And if I test with few conditions, I thought that maybe the fast one with few conditions would become the slow one with several hundred. I didn't find any test on the Internet

Comment: There are two basic ways of assessing performance: 1) reading the source code (of Pandas, in your case) and reasoning about its complexity and efficiency in terms of algorithms used; 2) profiling and benchmarking by running the same piece of code thousands of times and analyzing statistical properties of the time it took to run this code (at various levels of detail). You probably don't need to dig into Pandas' source code, so the remaining option is benchmarking and/or profiling

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. What is `df` if the error thinks `df["Short description"]`  is a `str`?

Comment: I don't know how to create an equivalent dataframe simply without giving private information. The dataframe contains only written information, in upper and lower case. And I have to look at the "short description" so a manually written and very variable text field, so I look if in this column, the value contains a precise value

Answer (score -1):

The return value of `df["Short Description"]` is already a str. You don't need to use `.str` you can directly use `.contains("e")`
Example:

```py
print(df["Short description"].contains("e"))
```

Comment: I tried but i got "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'"

Comment: `df["Short Description"]` is a Series since `df` is a `DataFrame`, not a dict

Comment: So, do you agree i have to use : "e" in df2["Short description"]: return "things" ?